# How to put javadoc on custom annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

I have following annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Column {
...
...
    /**
     * Defines title for the column
     * Default: 
     */
    String title() default "";

...
...
}
```

**When this annotation is used by eclipse editor, it does not display comments on the properties. How to enable those javadocs on annotation properties????**

**NOTE:** All annotations are built as jar file and added as target project's lib reference.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on my Eclipse and it works just fine for me.

Comment: did you build this as jar and added as classpath?

Comment: @Jian I am exporting generated class files & resources